# TinyCrayon Similar

Tags: ios, iphone, image-processing, image-editing

I'm trying to develop app to make image with full  transparency.

Mainly I need it smart selection just like TinyCrayon.

So how can I make similar algorithm to select the selected object?

this image

[image]

to become like this image 
[image]

using selection like this:

[image]

Comment: Ok.  I understand.  They are basically lying when they say it is free; it isn't free software in either sense of the word.  Unfortunately asking for off-site recommendations is off-topic for Stack Overflow.

Comment: @Paulw11 yes I know this link, but there is no source code, these are just an examples. also developer said 'By using TinyCrayon SDK, you agree to keep the banner ad embedded in TCMaskView fully viewable and clickable to the users.'

Comment: actually I'm asking for alternative either code or library. So I think stackoverflow is appropriate  site to ask for that

Comment: No, Sorry.  *Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, describe the problem and what has been done so far to solve it.*. A code-answer would be too broad.  So, either way it is off-topic.

Comment: @Paulw11 I update my question , can you help ?

Comment: what do you mean by image with full transparency?

Comment: @guru I update the question to explain what I need

Answer (score 2):

You can use openCV library along with grabcut algorithm:

https://docs.opencv.org/3.4.3/d8/d83/tutorial_py_grabcut.html